# how to show quotation marks inside of a msgbox

Tags: vb.net

Can someone please tell me a way (or similar) to use (") in a text in vb. 
eg. msgbox("some text here "other text here" more text" & vbnewline & "next line of text").

If you still dont get what I mean, all I need is this section ("other text") including the (") to show in a msgbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either escape the quote by another quote `Dim q as String = """"` would be one quote, or use `ControlChars.Quote`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use double quotes.

For example : Dim abc as string = "Using double ""quotes""

So for MsgBox you would do the same. MsgBox("Use double ""quotes"" to show quotes")

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the quotes never looks quite right to me.

I like using a fluent-ish API instead:

```
<Extension>
Public Function Quote(byval value as String) As String
  Return value & CHR(34)
End Function

<Extension>
Public Function SurroundWith(ByVal value As String, ByVal surround As String) As String
  Return surround & value & surround
End Function
```

### Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello there!  I'm Bob ".Quote & "Buddy".Quote & " Holly.")

Console.WriteLine("Hello there!  I'm Bob " & "Buddy".SurroundWith(CHR(34)) & " Holly.")
```